Change the double integral to an iterated integral
Given:
$$\iint_S (x+y)dA$$
such that the bounded region is given by a triangular area with vertices: $(0,0),(0,4),(1,4)$.
Now we have that $x = \frac{4}{y}$ and $x =0$ for the first iterated integral taking horizontal slices and for the second integral vertical slices we have from $x=0$ to $x=1$
$$\int_0^1\int_0^{4/y}(x+y)dxdy$$
am I correct?

$x=4/y$ is wrong (that would make a hyperbola). Also, $x=0$ is not a side of the triangle, so that is also wrong

Before setting up the integral, draw a picture of the triangle, and find equations for the lines that form its three sides.

Oh, and it seems like you are trying to use $x$ as the variable in both integrals (you say $x$ from $0$ to $4/y$ and $x$ from $0$ to $1$). You need need to use $x$ for the inner or outer only, and $y$ for the other one

y=$4x$ is the equation of the hypotenuse

what about $y/4$ as the first limit?

can anybody help me set up the second integral given that I change the axis to x= y/4

If you're integrating horizontally between $x=0$ and $x=y/4$, what are the minimum and maximum values of $y$? Look at your picture.

@MatthewLeingang I am not sure I think 0-4?

is it from 0 to 4?

@samsamradas Yes, the limits are either $(0\le x\le 1,\ 4x\le y\le 4)$ or $(0\le y\le 4,\ 0\le x\le y/4)$

The triangle has three sides: the vertical line $x=0$, the horizontal line $y=4$, and the diagonal line $y=4x$.
Moving from left-to-right, the bottom edge of $S$ is the line $y=4x$, and the top edge is $y=4$. The left extreme is at $x=0$, and the right one at $x=1$. Therefore
$$
   \iint_S f\,dA = \int_0^1\int_{4x}^4 f(x,y)\,dy\,dx
$$
If you'd rather move from bottom-to-top, the lower extreme is at $y=0$ and the upper one at $y=4$. The left edge is along $x=4$. You need to rewrite the equation $y=4x$ as $x=y/4$ to get $x$ as a function of $y$. Therefore
$$
   \iint_S f\,dA = \int_0^4\int_{0}^{y/4} f(x,y)\,dx\,dy
$$
